# DirectShow on multiple machines with wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, multithreading, directshow, parallel-processing

Is it any how possible to run DirectShow on multiple machines with wcf?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want DirectShow Editing Services on multiple machines in parallel with WCF (Asuming we have 1000 megaBYTES/s Computer Net) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606589/directshow-editing-services-on-multiple-machines-in-parallel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DirectShow and WCF are completely unrelated.

If your question is if you can stream a DirectShow graph using WCF to other computers then the answer is likely no.

Actually WCF can handle streaming data for SOME transports.
However neither DirectShow has direct support for this (you would have to develop your own graph components) nor has WCF any special media streaming capabilities.

Comment: Heh.. Thank you. But the Q was how to for example implement DS graph structure into WCF so that every instance of WCF would be a 1 DS filter or 1 filter group and WCF woud be a data transfer for connecting thous filters data streams.